# Simple HTTP server for logging requests only

Tags: http, logging, http-headers, httpserver, charles-proxy

I need to run a simple HTTP server that will only log incoming requests and nothing.

It should log whole requests' content. Like headers, cookies, body....

I need just simple solution that I can run in a few minutes and will work.

Implementation language is not important.

Something like Charles but HTTP server instead of proxy

Comment: try this https://webhook.site/

Answer (score 54):

For some super simple alternatives, there's netcat:

```
$ nc -l -p 8080
```

And python's inbuilt:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

(In recent versions of python, 3?) this is now:

```
$ python -m http.server 8080
```

Netcat won't serve responses so you may not get too far, SimpleHTTPServer won't show POST requests (at least). But occasionally I find both useful.

Comment: There are multiple versions of netcat out there with different behaviour, irritatingly. The -p flag tends to work even where it's optional.

Comment: For me on Mac OS X, `nc -l -p <port>` gave an error, while `nc -l <port>` worked but only kept nc listening for a single request. `nc -k -l <port>` keeps it going past the first request.

Comment: Be careful with the python http.server command, it will list your directory's files if you request '/' and allow you to download files.

Comment: `python -m http.server 8080` this one is interesting; But, can I make it to return 200 OK, instead of 404 Not Found?

Comment: It serves files from the directory you run it in, so if there's an index.html it'll serve that with a 200. If there's nothing in the directory you'll get 404s.

Answer (score 28):

If you are looking for online HTTP server which will record all requests' information, you can use [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/). (Update in 2020: Unfortunately, RequestBin was offline now.)

If you need to make your own HTTP *logging server*, Node.js + Express is a good candidate. It's very easy and quickly to make:

1. Install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org)
2. Install [Express generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) so that web application can be generated in seconds: `npm install express-generator -g`
3. Generate a web application and install all dependencies:

```
    express myapp
    cd myapp
    npm install
```

4. Edit `myapp/app.js` and insert following code block before the line `app.use('/', index);`:

```
    app.use(function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.headers);
      console.log(req.cookies);
      console.log(req.body);
      res.send('OK');
    });
```

5. That's it. Now run `DEBUG=myapp:* npm start` in console and start the web applicaiton. All HTTP requests sent to host `localhost:3000` will be recorded with their headers, cookies and body.
6. If you need to write these logs into a file, a logger module can be used, such as [log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log).

Comment: I have implemented the proposed nodejs solution here : https://github.com/humblewolf/loght

Comment: It seems the "RequestBin" website has been taken offline.

Comment: @humble_wolf Why using docker for something as simple as that?

Comment: @Chris So sad that RequestBin has been offline :(

Comment: @JeanPaul docker is even simpler :)